# Why does my GitHub Actions script cannot find my internal go package?

Tags: go, action, github-actions

I'm learning Go and want to make use of GitHub Actions. Everything is fine when working with just one package. But as soon as I define more than one package (more than the main package), I get stucked. On my desktop it does compile, but by using Actions script it does not and ends up in following error:

```
Run go build -v main.go
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "Landsat-Extractor/logger" in any of:
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.14.4/x64/src/Landsat-Extractor/logger (from $GOROOT)
    /home/runner/go/src/Landsat-Extractor/logger (from $GOPATH)
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The file structure is:

```
go
└───src
    └───Landsat-Extractor
        │   main.go
        │
        └───logger
        |   │   logger.go
        |
        └───.github
            └───workflows
                |   go.yml
```

On my local machine GOPATH is set to `go` of the previous file structure.

My Actions script go.yml is:

```
name: Go

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, feature_githubaction ]

jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Set up Go 1.x
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: ^1.14
      id: go

    - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build
      run: go build -v main.go
```

The main.go is:

```
package main

import (
    "Landsat-Extractor/logger"
)

func main() {

    logger.Create()
    defer logger.Destroy()

    logger.Info("A message")

}
```

The logger.go is:

```
package logger

// Create inits the Logger
func Create() {
    println("Creating")
}

// Info logs a message
func Info(msg string) {
    println(msg)
}

// Destroy closes writers
func Destroy() {
    println("Closing")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `~/go/src/Landsat-Extractor` run `go mod init`

This would help to resolve your module imports.